# Add marginals to data table?

Tags: r, data.table

What is the right way to add marginal sums to a data table?

What I do right now:

```
> (a <- data.table(x=c(1,2,1,2,2,3,3),y=c(10,10,20,20,30,30,40),z=1:7,key=c("x")))
   x  y z
1: 1 10 1
2: 1 20 3
3: 2 10 2
4: 2 20 4
5: 2 30 5
6: 3 30 6
7: 3 40 7
> (a <- a[a[,sum(z),by=x]])
   x  y z V1
1: 1 10 1  4
2: 1 20 3  4
3: 2 10 2 11
4: 2 20 4 11
5: 2 30 5 11
6: 3 30 6 13
7: 3 40 7 13
> setnames(a,"V1","x.z")
> setkeyv(a,"y")
> (a <- a[a[,sum(z),by=y]])
    y x z x.z V1
1: 10 1 1   4  3
2: 10 2 2  11  3
3: 20 1 3   4  7
4: 20 2 4  11  7
5: 30 2 5  11 11
6: 30 3 6  13 11
7: 40 3 7  13  7
> setnames(a,"V1","y.z")
```

I am pretty sure this is not The Right Way.

What is?

Comment: +1, very nice question. And a very nice answer from @Jilber. I've also made a small edit showing the different scenarios where and how you can use `:=`. Let me know if something's still unclear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One alternative is this one:

```
> a[,Sum:=sum(z), by="x"]
> a
   x  y z Sum
1: 1 10 1   4
2: 1 20 3   4
3: 2 10 2  11
4: 2 20 4  11
5: 2 30 5  11
6: 3 30 6  13
7: 3 40 7  13
```

---

#### Edit: Some more explanation on `:=` usage:

The `:=` operator enables **add/update** by *reference*. With this, you can:

- *add* new columns or *update* existing columns by reference

  ```
  DT[, x2 := x+1] # add one new column
  DT[, `:=`(x2 = x+1, y2 = y+1)] # adding more than 1 col
  DT[, x := x+1] # modify existing column
  ```
- *add* or *update* **certain rows** of new or existing columns by reference

  ```
  DT[x == 1L, y := NA] # modify 'y' just where expression in 'i' matches
  DT[x == 1L, `:=`(y = NA, z=NA)] # same but for multiple columns
  DT[x == 1L, newcol := 5L] # matched rows for 'newcol' will be 5, all other 'NA'
  ```
- *add* or *update* cols while **grouping**, by reference - by default, the computed result is recycled within each group.

  ```
  DT[, zsum := sum(z), by=x]
  ```

> Here, `sum(z)` returns 1 value for each group in `x`. The result is then recycled for length of *that* group and is added/updated by reference to `zsum`.

- *add* or *update* during a **by-without-by** operation. That is, when you perform a `data.table` *join* and you want to add/update column *while* joining:

  ```
  X <- data.table(x=rep(1:3, each=2), y=1:6, key="x")
  Y <- data.table(x=1:3, y=c(3L, 1L, 2L), key="x")
  X[Y, y.gt := y > i.y]
  ```
- Finally, you can also **remove** columns by reference (i.e. instantly even it's a 20GB table) :

  ```
  DT[, x := NULL] # just 1 column
  DT[, c("x","y") := NULL]   # 1 or more columns

  toRemove = c("x","y")
  DT[, (toRemove) := NULL]   # wrap with brackets to lookup variable
  ```

Hope this helps clarify the usage on `:=`. Also check out `?set`. It is similar to `:=`, but with the limitation that it *can not* be combined with *joins*. This allows for it to be faster inside a `for` loop (due to reduced overhead from not calling `[.data.table`) for all operations it is capable of than `:=`.

It can be quite handy, especially, in some scenarios. See [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808374/r-how-to-generate-a-linear-combination-of-variables-and-update-table-using-data/20808573#20808573) for a nice usage.