How can I split the values of ALL columns in a dataframe into two?
I have a data frame in R of the form below (but with about 200K columns):



1
2
3
4
5




AA
AA
TT
AG
CC


AT
AA
TA
GC
CC


AA
AT
TT
AG
CC



I need to split each column into two so that it looks like the following:



1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10




A
A
A
A
T
T
A
G
C
C


A
T
A
A
T
A
G
C
C
C


A
A
A
T
T
T
A
G
C
C



The function str_split_fixed() from the package stringr works well to split a single column into two the way that I need it to, but I can't figure out how to make this work across my entire data frame. Because I have so many columns in my real data, I can't just split all the columns manually.
I'm fairly new to coding, and have tried a for loop:
split_df <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = (2 *ncol(df)))

for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {
split_df[,i:i+1] <- str_split_fixed(df[,i], "", 2)
}

This creates a matrix that fills vertically and doesn't fill down the entire column.
Clearly I'm not doing this right, but I can't seem to fix it (especially as I'm not great at for loops). Are there any packages out there that could make this easier? Maybe a fix to this for loop? Or some other way to split the data in this data frame? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You say you have a data.frame, but your sample code shows a matrix. Which is it?

This is basically the same question; does the top answer solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174986/split-one-column-into-two

Another base R solution:
read.table(text = gsub('', ' ', do.call(paste0, df)), colClasses = 'character')

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  A  A  A  A  T  T  A  G  C   C
2  A  T  A  A  T  A  G  C  C   C
3  A  A  A  T  T  T  A  G  C   C


This is a clever and very elegant solution. +1!

in base R you can try
> as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(t(df), "")), nrow(df), byrow = TRUE))
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  A  A  A  A  T  T  A  G  C   C
2  A  T  A  A  T  A  G  C  C   C
3  A  A  A  T  T  T  A  G  C   C

The benchmarking for curiosity
microbenchmark(
    stringr = matrix(unlist(str_extract_all(t(df), boundary("character"))), nrow(df), byrow = TRUE),
    strsplit = matrix(unlist(strsplit(t(df), "")), nrow(df), byrow = TRUE),
    unit = "relative",
    check = "equal"
)

shows
Unit: relative
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  stringr 4.167347 3.820551 3.735045 3.968039 3.478943 3.620147   100
 strsplit 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100


The output doesn't match the desired. I believe you need to transpose the matrix first as I did in my answer.

@jblood94 aha, thanks for correcting me! yes, you are right that I missed t.

No problem. I didn't have time to benchmark, but I was curious about the performance of stringr and base for splitting out each character.

@jblood94 I just added a simple benchmarking

Very good. My guess is this will be the fastest of all the answers so far since it is vectorized. I imagine it will be noticeable with 200k columns.

@jblood94 I think that is one of the reasons I love base R so much :D

You can use str_split_fixed from stringr package and loop over all columns using sapply:
> library(stringr)
> matrix(sapply(df, str_split_fixed, "", 2), nrow = nrow(df))|>
    as.data.frame()
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  A  A  A  A  T  T  A  G  C   C
2  A  T  A  A  T  A  G  C  C   C
3  A  A  A  T  T  T  A  G  C   C

Sample data:
structure(list(X1 = c("AA", "AT", "AA"), X2 = c("AA", "AA", "AT"
), X3 = c("TT", "TA", "TT"), X4 = c("AG", "GC", "AG"), X5 = c("CC", 
"CC", "CC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))


If you're working with data frames, using strsplit with unnest_wider
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ strsplit(.x, ""))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(everything(), names_sep="") %>% 
  setNames(1:10)
# A tibble: 3 × 10
  `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`   `10` 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     A     A     A     T     T     A     G     C     C    
2 A     T     A     A     T     A     G     C     C     C    
3 A     A     A     T     T     T     A     G     C     C

Another base R approach, using apply
data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, \(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ""))))) |> setNames(1:10)
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 A A A A T T A G C  C
2 A T A A T A G C C  C
3 A A A T T T A G C  C

Note that numbers as column names should be avoided.
Data
df <- structure(list(`1` = c("AA", "AT", "AA"), `2` = c("AA", "AA", 
"AT"), `3` = c("TT", "TA", "TT"), `4` = c("AG", "GC", "AG"), 
    `5` = c("CC", "CC", "CC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))


library(stringr)

matrix(unlist(str_extract_all(t(df), boundary("character"))), nrow(df), byrow = TRUE)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#> [1,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "T"  "T"  "A"  "G"  "C"  "C"  
#> [2,] "A"  "T"  "A"  "A"  "T"  "A"  "G"  "C"  "C"  "C"  
#> [3,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "T"  "T"  "T"  "A"  "G"  "C"  "C"

